# Integração entre SpringSecurity e SpringData para usar SpEL

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-data

Boa tarde

Estou criando uma rotina onde preciso usar a SpEL para acessar dados do usuario logado (Authetication) diretamente no @Query do SpringData, segui o proprio tutorial do SpringData para realizar a configuração:

[SpringData with SpEL](https://spring.io/blog/2014/07/15/spel-support-in-spring-data-jpa-query-definitions)

Após seguir todo o tutorial criei todos as configurações necessárias:

**Implementação do suporte a extensão:**

```
public class ImplEvaluationContextExtension extends EvaluationContextExtensionSupport{

    @Override
    public String getExtensionId(){
        return "security";
    }

    @Override
    public SecurityExpressionRoot getRootObject() {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

        return new SecurityExpressionRoot(authentication) {};
    }
}
```

**Método criando o objeto**

```
    @Bean
    public EvaluationContextExtension securityExtension(){
        return new ImplEvaluationContextExtension();
    }
```

**Dependência Maven**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-data</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

**Erro ao tentar logar na aplicação**

```
aused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Authentication object cannot be null
at org.springframework.security.access.expression.SecurityExpressionRoot.      (SecurityExpressionRoot.java:61)
at br.com.wts.mobione.conf.security.SecurityEvaluationContextExtension$1. (SecurityEvaluationContextExtension.java:18)
at br.com.wts.mobione.conf.security.SecurityEvaluationContextExtension.getRootObject(SecurityEvaluationContextExtension.java:18)
at br.com.wts.mobione.conf.security.SecurityEvaluationContextExtension.getRootObject(SecurityEvaluationContextExtension.java:1)
```

Realizei alguns debugs e constatei que o Spring invoka o método **securityExtension()**, antes do processo de login ter sido concluído, devido a isso acontece a NullPointerException.

Alguém já conseguiu resolver este problema ?

Obrigado.